# How to debug standard library in C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder

In C++Builder(5,6...XE4) IDE if I set a breakpoint on, say: `memset(x,0,sizeof(y))`, and try to step into `memset()`, the debugger would silently step over it. In contrast, the VS debugger steps into the asm rtl sources. Is there a way to let the CBuilder debugger walk through rtl sources?

The project is compiled with debug info, rtl is linked statically, no delphi vcl/rtl involved.

Comment: Which version are you actually using? In 5 it worked once in a blue moon, in XE5 it works more often.  BTW 'memset' is probably implemented in assembly rather than C, so you'll have to swap to the CPU view to step into it. (The "step into" only steps into C or Pascal code).

Comment: Expected more deterministic then O(blue_moon_rising_chance)... ;)
Using version 5.0. Just trying to figure out how the standard library is really implemented in CBuilder. 
Inspected *.tds file for my app, it reports contents for every file except the standard library.
Turns out that the missing imported names <from stdlib> are fetched by the linker from whatever library was fed to the linker on the command line. 
Now that leads to the following: though the rtl sources were provided, no attempt had been made to provide a correspondence of source-to-lib by Borlands; Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can always link with static RTL and copy whichever file you are interested in into your project. Then you'll be able to step into it.

Comment: I had been moving along this direction too. Problem is that you can't tell which file you should be interested in. Would require either staffing all files into one directory or a bit of reverse engineering. Any way, I'll give it a try. If it proves to work - I will accept it as the Answer.